# How do I check if `JavaScriptSerializer` is working correctly or not using SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui

It's my first time in SoapUI and i'm curious to know if is there any way to send data in JSON format to check if my Web service is working properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send JSON data to a web service with SoapUI.

You first need to add the web service you want to test in the 'Services' section of the tree.  Once you have defined the service, there's panel that allows you to define a payload to submit to the service.  The Media type dropdown indicates the type of data, the default is 'application/xml'.  You can change the dropdown to application/json.

If the above doesn't mean a great deal to you, I suggest running through some of the tutorials on the SmartBear site whilst you get some basic familiarity with the tool.